# Wordpress Woocommerce REST API V3 attributes and terms

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I woocommerce you can create Attributes, like Color
These attributes can have terms,  like red, green, white. Later on, you can add these attributes to a product.

I know how to add these attributes by means of the API, like described here:
http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product-attribute

I've been searching for hours, but there seems to be no way to add terms with the API.   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You add terms with the Update A Product api, [here](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product):

You make a PUT request: `/wc-api/v3/products/<id>`

In the request body you send:
`{"product":{"categories":[...],"tages":[...]}}`

Comment: Attributes, categories, tags....  Very confusing. 
I've added an attribute, now I want to add terms, but you tell me I have to add categories and tags. Can you elaborate on that a bit more? Say I have an attribute pa_color  and I want to add   red and green to that?

Answer (score 0):

Since WooCommerce 2.5 you have new endpoint for adding attributes term. Just look at the documentation.

http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-attribute-terms

For example for creating term for the specific attribute you can **POST** to endpoint

```
/wc-api/v3/products/attributes/<attribute_id>/terms
```

JSON message:

```
{
  "product_attribute_term": {
    "name": "Black"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It accepts the attribute slug/taxonomy name; Just use this one:

```
example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=pa_compatible-for&attribute_term=249
```

I know it's not documented properly!
Have a good time.